# how do I import a table DIRECTLY into a Python dataframe within databricks?

Tags: python, databricks

currently working within a dev environment in Databricks using a notebook to apply some Python code to analyse some dummy data (just a few 1,000 rows) held in within a database table, I then deploy this to the main environment and run it on the real data, (100's of millions of rows)

to start with I just need values from a single column that meet a certain criteria,  in order to get at the data I'm currently doing this:

1. spk_data = spark.sql("SELECT field FROM database.table WHERE field == 'value'")
2. data = spk_data.toPandas()

then the rest of the Python notebook does its thing on that data which works fine in the dev environment but when I run it for real it falls over at line 2 saying it's out of memory

I want to import the data DIRECTLY into the Pandas dataframe and so remove the need to convert from Spark as I'm assuming that will avoid the error but after a LOT of Googling I still can't work out how, the only thing I've tried that appears syntactically valid is:

data = pd.read_table (r'database.table')

but just get:

'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'

(nb. unfortunately I have no control over the content, form or location of the database I'm querying)

Comment: The `toPandas()` operation collects the table as a dataframe in memory on the driver node (the pandas dataframe is not distributed), so this is probably where you're getting out of memory issues. Spark uses [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation#:~:text=In%20programming%20language%20theory%2C%20lazy,avoids%20repeated%20evaluations%20(sharing).) and so it might seem like the `toPandas()` operation has run, but my bet is that your data is just too big to load into memory.

Comment: thanks for this, you're probably right but I was asked to try and find a way to remove the conversation in order to confirm

Answer (score 1):

You've to use [pd.read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) for this case.

Comment: thank you! THIS is what I've been looking for :)

Comment: @dat_tester If this answer helped you, please accept it (you'll earn 2+ rep by that).

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is very likely to be untrue.

Spark is a distributed computation engine, pandas is a single-node toolset. So when you run a query on milions of rows it's likely to fail. When doing df.toPandas, Spark moves all of the data to your driver node, so if it's more than driver memory, it's going to fail with out of memory exception. In other words, if your dataset is larger then memory, pandas are not going to work well.

Also, when using pandas on databricks you are missing all of the benefits of using the underlying cluster. You are just using the driver.

There are two sensible options to solve this:

- redo your solution using spark
- use [koalas](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which has API mostly compatible with pandas

Comment: thanks and yes, agreed, rewriting it all using spark is probably the best solution long term however the immediate task at hand here was to try and make this work with some existing Python code,

Comment: +1 to the suggestion of koalas.  It's a pandas API on Spark, so you should really take a look at that to see if all of your pandas functions are supported.  If so, it could be a very simple code change - importing koalas as ks instead of pandas as pd.